# Socket.io double events, solved for connect BUT not disconnect

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I'm new to socket.io and next.JS. After getting socket.io integrated in to Next I noticed connect code was firing twice, doubling my connection count (which I need to be accurate).

I googled a lot but did not find a solution that worked, including *socket.once('connect')*. I fixed this by creating a **manual** connect event and emitting from the client on startup. I can now see an accurate connection count as long as no one disconnects.

As for disconnecting I'm seeing the same problem, where disconnect fires twice per user, but I don't know how to manually emit on the client whenever a disconnection happens.

Any advice on how to emit a manual disconnect from the client?

Or a new approach? Maybe use a set to hold client ids instead of incrementing an int? Might be bad for performance with the repeated collection counting though (each user will be accessing the total count very often, maybe every second).

**server code**:

```
const SERVER_STATE = {
  totalConnections: 0
} 

// socket.io server
io.on('connection', socket => {

  socket.once('userConnectOnce', () => {
    SERVER_STATE.totalConnections++;
    socket.emit('message', `Welcome from server. There are a total of ${SERVER_STATE.totalConnections} connections.`);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', `New user joined. There are a total of ${SERVER_STATE.totalConnections} connections.`);
  });

  socket.once('disconnect', () => {       // this fires more than once
    SERVER_STATE.totalConnections--;
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', `Other user disonnected. There are now ${SERVER_STATE.totalConnections} connections.`);
  });

});
```

**client code**:

```
const Index = () => {
  const socket = useSocket('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  socket.emit('userConnectOnce', 'client-initiated userConnectOnce');

  return (
    <></>
  );
};
```

Note: **useSocket()** is custom hook from the next examples repo to wrap socket.on() inside useEffect() and return the socket. I can't find the link, and not sure its relevant, but here's some of the code:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io();

export default function useSocket(eventName, cb) {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(eventName, cb);

    return function socketCleanup() {
      socket.off(eventName, cb);
    }
  }, [eventName, cb]);

  return socket;
}
```

Comment: Did you make the `useSocket` hook yourself or are you using the `useSocket` hook from socket.io? Can you post the code?

Comment: Its from a next example repo. I can't find the link so I've added to code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by refactoring, and it works now.

```
const SERVER_STATE = {
  users: [ {userId: 123, socketId: 456} ]
}
```

I generate a userId with UUID on the client side and persist it with localStorage. When connecting I add it to SERVER_STATE.users along with the socketId, and if its already there, I update the socketId, just to ensure socketId stays current through any duplicate calls.

On disconnect, I filter the users array. Use socketId to get userId, then remove any items with that userId.

Obviously the total connections I need is the length of users array. I'll probably cache this as an int in SERVER_STATE so I don't need to count it excessively.

Answer (score 2):

If your `Index` component is rendering more than once, use socket hook will run again. As you can see in the `useSocket` hook, `useEffect` depends on the `cb`, and you are creating new `callback` every time the `Index` component is run.

Comment: I'm using Next.JS, so Index.js is a page. Its file-based routing. There's no place in my own code where I'm using Index as a component - its just under the hood of Next. However, I added a console log just inside the Index declaration and I noticed two things. 1) Client logs it out twice, so YOU'RE RIGHT. I just don't yet understand how. 2) My manual connect event seemed to solve connect doubling, but actual this setup causes my total connections to decrement on each page refresh (single client open). Ugh. At least that wasn't happening when my connects were doubled. Any ideas?

Comment: `Index` is still a react component, that can render any number of times. Try memoizing the callback.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I don't fully understand where to try useCallback so I tried various places without success: the returned callback from the useSocket declaration, the lambda argument in the useSocket implementation, and even the entire useSocket exported function (lol). Admittedly, I also don't fully understand the useSocket hook. But it seems to me the socket.off in the useEffect cleanup function could be the problem. But things get worse if I comment it out.

Comment: I tried moving socket creation from useSocket into Index and passing the socket into useSocket(). Increased total connections. Maybe I need to count connections in a way that doesn't involve counting actual sockets, if that's possible.